# Convert from string to binary in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, binary, type-conversion

Let's say that I have the string "A3C0", and I want to store the binary value of it in a Boolean array.

After the conversion (from string to binary) the result should be = 1010001111000000

Then I want to store it in this array,

```
dim bits_array(15) as Boolean
```

at the end:

```
bits_array(0)=0
bits_array(1)=0
 .
 .
 .
 .
bits_array(15)=1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy.

```
Function HexStringToBinary(ByVal hexString As String) As String
    Dim num As Integer = Integer.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.HexNumber)
    Return Convert.ToString(num, 2)
End Function
```

Sample Usage:

```
Dim hexString As String = "A3C0"
Dim binaryString As String = HexStringToBinary(hexString)
MessageBox.Show("Hex: " & hexString & "    Binary: " & binaryString)
```

To get the binary digits into an array, you can simply do:

```
Dim binaryDigits = HexStringToBinary(hexString).ToCharArray
```

Comment: Great! But what is NumberStyles? Shouldn't it be declared?

Comment: @Marine1, NumberStyles is an Enum and HexNumber is one of the members inside it. It is already declared. You can just simply use it.

Comment: @Marine1, Pradeep is not correct. It requires `System.Globalization`.

Answer (score 1):

Let `s` be the input string with value **A3C0**, `output` be a variable to store the output.
loop will iterate each letter in the input and store it in the temporary variable `temp`. Now see the code:

```
Dim s As String = "A3C0"
Dim output As String = ""
Dim temp As String = ""
For i As Integer = 1 To Len(s)
    temp = Mid(s, i, 1)
    output = output & System.Convert.ToString(Asc(temp), 2).PadLeft(4, "0")
    ' converting each letter into corresponding binary value
    'concatenate it with the output to get the final output 
Next
MsgBox(output)' display the binary equivalent of the input `s` 
Dim array() As Char = output.ToArray()' convert the binary string  to binary array
```

Hope that this is actually you are expected.

Comment: Actually I want to convert the number from Hex to binary, and I think you convert it from ASCII to binary.
Anyways thanks for your help